# Google Speech-to-text API, InvalidArgument: 400 Must use single channel (mono)

Tags: python, google-cloud-speech

I keep getting this error `InvalidArgument: 400` in google Speech-to-text, and the problem seems to be that I an using a 2 channel audio(Stereo), and the API is waiting for a wav in (Mono).

If I convert the file in a audio editor it might work, but I cannot use an audio editor to convert a batch of files. Is there a way to change the Audio type in either Python or Google Cloud.

Note: I already tried with the "wave module" but I kept getting an error #7 for file type not recognize(I couldn't read the wav file with the module wave from Python)

> -ERROR- InvalidArgument: 400 Must use single channel (mono) audio, but WAV header indicates 2 channels.

Answer (score 21):

Assuming you're using the *google-cloud-speech* library, you could use the `audio_channel_count` property in your `RecognitionConfig` and specify the number of channels in the input audio data (it defaults to one channel(mono)). You could do something like this:

```
from google.cloud import speech

client = speech.SpeechClient()
results = client.recognize(
    audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(
        uri = 'gs://your-bucket/recording.wav',
    ),
    config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding = 'LINEAR16',
        language_code = 'en-US',
        sample_rate_hertz = 44100,
        audio_channel_count = 2,
    ),
)
```

See the [API doc](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig) for further info.

Comment: I already tried that and I get this error. "InvalidArgument: 400 Invalid recognition 'config': bad channel count."

Comment: config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.MULAW,
    sample_rate_hertz=8000,
    language_code=first_lang,
    alternative_language_codes=[second_lang],
    enable_speaker_diarization=True,
    audio_channel_count=2,
    diarization_speaker_count=2,
    enable_separate_recognition_per_channel=True,
    enable_word_time_offsets=True,
    max_alternatives=2)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the below function to dynamically return audio channel & frame rate.

It takes the audio file path and returns frame rate and number of channels.

```
def frame_rate_channel(audio_file_name):
    print(audio_file_name)
    with wave.open(audio_file_name, "rb") as wave_file:
        frame_rate = wave_file.getframerate()
        channels = wave_file.getnchannels()
        return frame_rate,channels
```